# Wrote this kotlin code on my fragment of authentication with firebase and am not getting response

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

```
class SignUpFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false)

    }
}



class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sign_up)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        actionBar!!.title = "REGISTER"
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        val btonRegister1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btonRegister1)
        btonRegister1.setOnClickListener {
            val editEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editEmail)
            val editPassword = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editPassword)
            if (editEmail.text.trim().toString().isNotEmpty() || editPassword.text.trim().toString()
                    .isNotEmpty()
            ) {
                createUser(editEmail.text.trim().toString(), editPassword.text.trim().toString())
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Input Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }

    }

    fun createUser(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.e("Task Message", "SUCCESSFUL...");
                    val intent = Intent(this, DashBoard::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    Log.e("Task Message", "Failed..." + task.exception);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you completed your project setup on Firebase and on Android end completely? Your code looks correct. Perhaps there is an issue in the setup. Make sure you have the config json added to your project.

Comment: yeah but cant connect to firebase

Comment: The buttons are not functional too

Comment: If you are unable to connect to firebase, perhaps that itself is the issue. Also, regarding the button, have you added them to the layout?

Comment: Yes, and how do I use intent inside a fragment according to my code am suspecting its the problem am used to working with activities.

Comment: Please google this and try to figure this out. There are many many tutorials and documentations explaining this. Once you have a very specific problem which you are unable to figure out after trying out everything else then post a question. Then we will be able to help you out better as well. Best of luck!